# UIView device rotation iPad/iPhone in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, rotation

I am new in iPhone/iPad development I am getting a problem in rotation. I want to rotate a `UIView` according to device rotation iPad/iPhone with full content with the size and position sometimes.  Please help me out and give me sample code or any useful link.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate any view according to device rotation , Just goto Interface Builder and set the view sizes in the size inspector as shown in the following image.

[image]

or else, you can set using code,

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: I am already try this..I am still getting problem in Rotation of UIView the content of View like images , labels , buttons etc... can you give me sample code or reference for this... Is it possible through coding..??

Comment: I have an hierarchy like MyContorller->1. UiVIew - >1.1 UIView and 1.2- UIVieww with some images and other controls UIView is moving correctly but images are not moving properly??? can you help me out..?

Comment: For that, you need to create a notification, that will raise when there is a rotation of main view. Write notification responders in each subView. And write rotate method your self like view.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,self.view.frame.size.width-100,self.view.frame.size.height-100).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Interface Builder -> Size Inspector ->AutoSizing

Select all the Outer Bars and Un-select the inner bars. :-)